# Setup .htacces for non-ww and with ssl on multi domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been looking all around the web but can't find a clean solution.
Im not an hero in .htaccess rules but i would love to have some rules that will force the user to https and non-www for all the domains on that server / installation.

Atm i got this but im stuck;

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also make sure WP permalink has `https` and `non-www` URL in site and home URLs.

Comment: But doesn't this redirect all to domain.com instead of the initial domain? So i would like to have several domains (aaa.com, bbb.com, ccc.com) and all need to make use of non-ww and ssl.

Comment: You didn't mentions having so many domains in your question. If that is the case then you can put a condition like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]` on top that 301 rule.

Comment: so for each domains i must add that rule?